# React, "this", cloneElement and es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am wondering how ES6 and cloneElement works when you pass it a function. I need to reference state in the parent component's state but `this` references the child component and not the parent.

Below is the code in regular JavaScript to make it work, after first writing it in ES6 and banging my head on the keyboard I decided to see if it was ES6 so I refactored and it works just fine.

I just want to write it in ES6 because everything else is but this has stumped me.

This is my component in ES5:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  content: function() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
     return React.cloneElement(child, {
       passThisFunc: this.passThisFunc
     })
    }.bind(this));
  },

  passthisfunc: function(component) {
    // returns the components props
    console.log(this);

    // Returns the component so I can do component.props.name
    console.log(component);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.content }
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

And then in its children:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.props.passThisFunc(this);
  }

  render: function().....
});
```

The components are not that different in ES6, it is really what is referenced when `this` is logged.

Any help in refactoring (especially the parent component) would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
Here is the ES6 Example I tried:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  content() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
     return React.cloneElement(child, {
       passThisFunc: this.passThisFunc
     })
    }.bind(this));
  }

  passthisfunc(component) {
    // returns the components props
    console.log(this);

    // Returns the component so I can do component.props.name
    console.log(component);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.content }
      </div>
    )
  }
};

class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.passThisFunc(this);
  }

  render(){...}
};
```

Comment: Can you please fix the syntax errors in `content`?

Comment: ES6 doesn't change anything about how `this` works. What value did you expect for `this` if not `child.props`?

Comment: What I have in `content` is essentially the same as what I have in my current implementation and it works just fine, what are the syntax errors?  

Also on your second question I want to do something like:
`this.setState({ test: 'test' })`    

So I guess I expect it to be `this` to equal the parent component in like it does in ES5.

Comment: The `.map(` call misses its closing parenthesis, and in that object literal you're passing to `React.createClass({…})` the first property is delimited with `;` instead of a comma, and the second misses the comma completely.

Comment: Good call, thanks. It is updated.

Comment: Wait, in ES5 the `this` in `passthisfunc` does refer to the parent component? Is React doing some autobinding here? You're calling `this.props.passThisFunc(this);`, which would mean that the receiver is `this.props`.

Comment: @Bergi _ES6 doesn't change anything about how `this` works_ – unless you use arrow functions ;-)

Comment: You are right, `this` in `passThisFunc` refers to the parent component in ES5. [Here is a link](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/src/main.js#L424) to another example of it working in ES5. But in ES6 `this` refers to the `this.props`. At least in this example when I run `console.log(this);`. So when I try to `this.setState` `setState` is a undefined function.

Comment: @Mathletics: Sure, it does introduce new concepts (arrow functions, modules, generator functions, …) for which `this` has it's own, new semantics, but existing code with `function` should continue to work the same.

Comment: @RileyBracken _in ES6 `this` refers to the `this.props`_ – no it doesn't. sounds like you're doing something wrong. Can you post your ES6 example?

Comment: @Bergi absolutely. I was just being pedantic, hence the wink.

Comment: Added the ES6 example.

Comment: @RileyBracken do yourself a favor and read about [smart and dumb components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0); this thing looks needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [autobinding](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html) that `React.createClass` did feature [was removed](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding) for ES6 classes (see also [this article](http://www.ian-thomas.net/autobinding-react-and-es6-classes/)). So you'll have to do it manually now:

```
…
  content: function() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
     return React.cloneElement(child, {
       passThisFunc: this.passThisFunc.bind(this)
     })
    }.bind(this));
  },
…
```

---

But you wouldn't really do this in ES6. Rather, you'd use an arrow function in the first place, which features a lexical `this` binding:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.passthisfunc = (component) => {
      // returns the parent
      console.log(this);

      // Returns the component so I can do component.props.name
      console.log(component);
    };
  }
  content() {
    return React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, {
        passThisFunc: this.passThisFunc
      });
    );
  }
  …
}
```

Comment: Note: arrow functions re-create the function every render - which is a micro-perf hit to be weighed against the much cleaner syntax.

Comment: @AshleyCoolman Only when declared inside `render` (or a method called by it), which I have not done afaik