# React, cloneElement - invariant error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My team has been trying to think ahead on the topic of form validation using react components.

We've been following a guide we've seen [here](http://christianalfoni.github.io/javascript/2014/10/22/nailing-that-validation-with-reactjs.html) which looks really awesome and well thought out.

There's a property on the component here that looks a like this:

```
registerInputs: function (children) {
  React.Children.forEach(children, function (child) {
    if (child.props.name) {
      child.props.attachToForm = this.attachToForm;
      child.props.detachFromForm = this.detachFromForm;
    }

    if (child.props.children) {
      this.registerInputs(child.props.children);
    }
  }.bind(this));
},
attachToForm: function (component) {
  this.inputs[component.props.name] = component;
},
detachFromForm: function (component) {
  delete this.inputs[component.props.name];
}
```

The problem with this is attaching props this way gives you a warning in react, it suggests to use cloneElement instead.  It DOES work though, it just gives some console warnings which I don't like to see.

So in ES6 fashion, my team came up with this:

```
registerInputs = children => {
    React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
        if (child.props.name) {
            React.cloneElement(child, {
                attachToForm: this.attachToForm,
                detachFromForm: this.detachFromForm
            })
            //child.props.attachToForm = this.attachToForm;
            //child.props.detachFromForm = this.detachFromForm;
        }
        if (child.props.children) {
            this.registerInputs(child.props.children);
        }
    })
}
attachToForm = component => {
    this.inputs[component.props.name] = component;
    this.model[component.props.name] = component.state.value;
}
detachFromForm = component => {
    delete this.inputs[component.props.name];
    delete this.model[component.props.name];
}
```

This does **not** work, we get an invariant error saying the dom node wasn't found (the one that says you either have a `<tbody>` missing etc.).

To clarify: If we comment out the cloneElement block, and uncomment the explicit declaration of the prop on the children, it works -but with the warnings.

We've tried a few other solutions including the similar question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841949/react-this-cloneelement-and-es6)
but this did not work for us.  We also tried mapping, which seems to be common in the react docs and returning the new array with the new props that way, but we kept getting the invariant error.

**How come setting the props on the children works when doing so in object dot notation works (though advises against it) and the cloned element approach does not?**

Console logging seems to indicate that cloning the children and adding the props the way we have done it above is not actually adding anything to the props object.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [formsy-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formsy-react) library, from the same author, which implements an [updated version](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react/blob/master/src/main.js#L182-L210) of the method exposed in the  blog post:

```
traverseChildrenAndRegisterInputs: function(children) {

    if (typeof children !== 'object' || children === null) {
        return children;
    }
    return React.Children.map(children, function(child) {

        if (typeof child !== 'object' || child === null) {
            return child;
        }

        if (child.props && child.props.name) {

            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                _attachToForm: this.attachToForm,
                _detachFromForm: this.detachFromForm,
                _validate: this.validate,
                _isFormDisabled: this.isFormDisabled,
                _isValidValue: function(component, value) {
                    return this.runValidation(component, value).isValid;
                }.bind(this)
            }, child.props && child.props.children);
        } else {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {}, this.traverseChildrenAndRegisterInputs(child.props && child.props.children));
        }

    }, this);

}
```